# Open herf in new window after jQuery animation is complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a simple slide animation after an img link is clicked.
The client is requesting the link open in a new window/tab.
Every option I have tried `window.open`or `window.location = href;` with the `var href = this.href;` set, does not work.

```
$("#coatings").click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         var href = this.href;

         $("#sqeeguee_rightLink").fadeIn(100).animate({
            right:'-=450px'                 
         }, 2000,
         function() {
             window.location = href;
         });
     });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sqeeguee_rightLink"></div>
        <a href="url here" target="_blank" id="coatings"><img src="coatings.jpg" width="456" height="592" alt="" /></a>
```

Any input would be great!

Comment: it either does not open in a new window, only plays the animation and goes nowhere or just goes to the link and skips the animation all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've quoted presumably "doesn't work" because after the animation is complete, the new URL is opened in the same window. You've cancelled the event that would have opened the new window (by calling `event.preventDefault()`).

Your `window.open` attempt fails because modern browsers only allow JavaScript code to open windows *during* the processing of a user-initiated event (such as a `click`). Your animation is started by the user-initiated event, but then allows the event handler to complete, so when you try to do `window.open`, as far as the browser is concerned, you're opening a spam window, and its popup block prevents that from happening. :-)

If your goal is to show an animation on the current window, and then open a new window when it's done, I'm afraid there's no clean way to do that. You *might* be able to allow the original new window to open but get it to go to the background (a "pop-under"), and then when the animation is complete, bring it to the foreground. I can't see that as a great user experience, though.

Comment: And what about opening the new window with `height=0` then setting the new height after animation completes, it could be another alternative to try it out.

Comment: @Nelson: Most browsers won't let you do that anymore, they enforce a minimum size (or open it in a tab).

Comment: Guess I should have stated that I do not want a new window but to open as a tab. The href is pointing to a different domain.

Comment: @Eric: The answer's the same, I'm afraid. (And it doesn't matter whether these are the same domain or not.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the href not captured properly, not the way you want to open the link.

If you need to open the href attribute of the clicked link (wrapping up the image), try this:

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
```

Inside your event handler method.

Rob